# Techniques for observing runtime state in C

Tags: c, serialization, state, monitoring

What are the techniques for C programs which allow easily inspecting the state of the embedded device, through a communication link?

For example, for a microcontroller device which communicates with other devices, an external device might want to perform queries similar to:

1. What is the battery level of this device?
2. When was this device last turned off?
3. Are other devices connected to this device?
4. Which IP addresses are these devices connecting from?
5. etc.

There are ways we usually do this in our projects which involve:

1. Making lots of state shared (i.e. global). Communication module receiving these requests accesses the global state in order to transmit it.
2. Defining request parsers and response serializers for the involved data. These legacy projects often have lots of different cookies, each of which represents a certain request message, and then certain data is sent back, usually serialized on the fly according to an agreed message format (or protocol).

Are there some ways to implement this common functionality so that:

1. We can prevent breaking encapsulation by exposing the state, and
2. Remove the amount of coding for each new request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a symbol table, or map file, based query system where you have a generic query mechanism which requests the data at a specific location and with a specific size then decode the response on it being received.

Of course your querying software will need to know the exact version of the target being queried and have the map for each supported version, this is usually handled by having a fixed location for the version information.

The other issue is that you will not be able to access any dynamically allocated data locations, (e.g. `malloc` created), unless you have a two step process, *(request the location of the storage then request the data from that location),* - however the use of `malloc` is not generally considered best practice in the embedded world and is often forbidden in the coding standards if you are doing high reliability or safety critical work.

If you are only needing to provide this during development an test the use of a tool such as the gdb remote debugger is the most usual way to go.

Comment: This is also a possibility since malloc is not used. This probably means the map file for each build should be copied/committed to the querying system side. Do you know of systems where this has been deployed in practice?

Comment: @Lou - Yes, 100s of embedded systems use this sort of technique. I have encountered similar, (sometimes well wrapped), in fields such as flight simulator visual systems, sonar processing systems, almost every CAN-Bus system uses something similar and of course GDB and most other debuggers that allow remote debugging of embedded systems use this under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, accepted the answer. I wonder what your feelings are about the ["abuse of x-macros"](https://natecraun.net/articles/struct-iteration-through-abuse-of-the-c-preprocessor.html)? I stumbled upon the article while looking for ideas. Struct definitions become more convoluted, but it seems the complexity of the entire system is lower in runtime (no need to track the fw version+map file on the other end, presumably smaller chance of reading gibberish, works out of the box even if the release is not an "official" one). I am referring to the idea of getting struct contents simply by its name.

Answer (score 1):

One answer to the first concern is inversion of control. Instead of the communication module search about for the relevant state, the other modules can simply inform the communication module when the state changes. This adds some overheads. First, the communication module is then essentially going to have a copy of the queryable state, though, depending on your concurrency concerns, having a pointer to larger pieces of state would be fine. This also adds overhead when updating the state (e.g. a function call), though in cases where this is a problem it may be okay to only notify the communication module of some updates (e.g. 1 in every 1000). Of course, this will mean that the queried result may be stale. This also means that making a new piece of state queryable requires changing the module responsible for it to notify the communication module. That said, such a change would likely be necessary anyway unless *all* of your state was global.

The benefits of this approach are first, encapsulation which means if some module changes how it represents its state, no changes are needed elsewhere in the system. Furthermore, while the approach I describe allows multiple modules to overwrite other modules state in the communication module, this only affects query results and not the operation of other modules. This is also not very likely to happen though. Second, the communication module can store its state in a way that is convenient for generic processing. Conceptually, it's just a (typed) key-value store. Allowing metadata queries, such as returning the list of supported keys, also becomes straightforward to do generically. The actual representation can be a normal hash table or an array per type of data (e.g. integers vs byte sequences) indexed by sequentially and manually allocated keys. Depending on the concurrency situation, this can also give a more consistent snapshot as other modules can notify the communication module of changes when its state is consistent, rather than the communication module potentially reading state that is in the middle of being changed.

Turning to your second concern, it should be clear how you can build a simple protocol for querying this data. It's very likely you can use some "standard" protocol for this purpose. However, I suspect you have to deal with pre-existing protocols that are idiosyncratic, i.e. each request has its own format and expects the response in a request-specific format. There's likely some systematization that you can leverage, but ultimately, as long as you need to support such requests there's nothing to do but write a bunch of special-case code. You can make or use libraries and tools that can simplify that. What you can do, though, is potentially centralize this code in a proxy or at least a layer in front of the communication model by writing code to convert from the legacy protocol formats to a more generic format.

If the above approach seems like it would have too much runtime overhead, there are things that can be done to mitigate it (e.g. packaging an entire component's state into a struct or collection of arrays and passing only a pointer to it to the communication module). These will likely bring back some of the downsides and/or add complexity. If your constraints are that tight, you may find some inspiration from the [Virgil language](http://compilers.cs.ucla.edu/virgil/overview.html) ([code](https://github.com/titzer/virgil)).